# Create localized django app and use the localization from other app

Tags: python-3.x, django, internationalization

I have the following problem:

I created a Django app (*app1*) and then installed it in other one (*app2*). Now I'm trying to make the internationalization of the site, but I want to be able to use the installed app translations and I cannot even compile them.

Some useful information:

**APP 1**

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── app1
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── locale/
│   │   ├── en-us
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── es
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   └── pr
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           └── django.po
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static/
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
└── setup.py
```

**APP 2 (the one that has APP 1 installed)**

```
├── app2/
│   ├── locale/
│   │   ├── en-us/
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES                                                                                                                                                                                                              
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   ├── es/
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       ├── django.mo
│   │   │       └── django.po
│   │   └── pr/
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           ├── django.mo
│   │           └── django.po 


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'app1.apps.App1SiteConfig',
    'app2.apps.App2SiteConfig',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

LANGUAGES = (
   ('en-us', _('English')),
   ('es', _('Spanish')),
   ('pt', _('Portuguese'))
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "app2", "locale"),
)
```

Basically, the desired TODOs are:

- compile the .mo's from *App1*
- use the *App1* transalations (it has its own templates and models so ideally they would be used there)

What I don't want:

- compile the *App1* .mo's from django-admin of *App2* and then translate it there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. finally I managed to solve this by my way..

With the virtualenv activated I moved to *App1* dir and executed `django-admin compilemessages`, the .mo's has been created in the right path (`app1/locale/<lang>/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo`) and they're able to be used from the site.